# Is it good practice to set the baseURL as window.location.origin for production / heroku deployment?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, axios, gridfs

I'm currently using GridFS to store images, and the only way I can successfully render them in React is by getting res.config.baseURL and concatenating my api path and image filename. When I set up my baseURL for production, I am using window.location.origin. Is this a safe method? If not is there a preferred method for setting the baseURL for production when deploying apps to heroku?

**api.js**

```
const axios = require("axios");
let axiosInstance;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: window.location.origin + "/"
  });
} else {
  axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/"
  });
}

module.exports = axiosInstance;
```

**React component**
Omitted some code for brevity

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import API from "../../utils/api";
import isEmpty from "../../validation/is-empty";

class Images extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      images: [],
      baseurl: "",
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getImages();
  }

  getImages = () => {
    API.get(`/api/files/GET/images`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.config.baseURL);
        const images = res.data;
        const baseurl = res.config.baseURL;
        this.setState({
          images,
          baseurl,
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
  render() {
    const {
      images,
      baseurl,
    } = this.state;
    let imageList;

    if (!isEmpty(images)) {
      imageList = images.map(i => (
        <div key={i._id} className="col-md-8 shadowed mb-3 mt-3">
          <img
            src={baseurl + "api/files/GET/image/" + i.filename}
            className="img-fluid d-block mx-auto fileImg mt-3 rounded"
            alt={baseurl}
          />
          <div className="col-md-12 text-center pb-3 pt-3">
            <p>
              Path:{" "}
              <span className="text-success">
                {baseurl + "api/files/GET/image/" + i.filename}
              </span>
            </p>
            <button
              className="btn btn-danger"
              onClick={this.deleteFile.bind(this, i._id)}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      ));
    }

    return (
      <div className="row">
        {imageList}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Images;
```

Comment: Isn't the base url just your website url? Also, do you have access to the `window` on your Node server? You can probably just hard-code the string on your server. Heroku also allows you to set environment variables for your application on their client.

Comment: Yes correct, but for the sake of creating re-usable code, I wouldn't want to hard-code the baseURL. I have set up a few config vars in heroku, and I've tried adding my website url as a config var, but that didn't change the baseURL.